# Giving a unique text to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So... I have four `div`s on a page. All four of them belong to the `class` `foobar`. What I wanna do here is give each of them a value from a certain `Array` in JavaScript. Do note I am using jQuery 3.2.1.

My JavaScript:

```
var $elements = jQuery.makeArray($(".foobar"));
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function (x) {
  $elements.forEach(function (y) {
    y.text(x.toString());
  });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
```

And as always, it does not work. Basically what I wanna do here is give each `Number` in that `Array` as the `text()` for each `div`.

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Alrighty!

Comment: so you want the first div to have value 1, second 2, and so on ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen That's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bj3s92gr/
Bassicaly you have to bucle the divs with class foobar, and assing the position of the array in the html.

```
var $elements = $(".foobar");
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$elements.each(function(e){
    $(this).html($arr[e]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the same text to every element inside inner loop. Try this

```
var $elements = $(".foobar");
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function (x, i) {
  $($elements[i]).text(x)
});
```

Or use [`.text(func)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
var texts = [1,2,3,4];
var $elements = $(".foobar").text(function(i) {
   return texts[i];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of numbers, traverse thru all the .foobar elements, and assign a value from the array.

```js
var $elements = jQuery.makeArray($(".foobar"));
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var count = 0;
$(".foobar").each(function() {
  $(this).text(numbers[count]);
  count++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My HTML:

<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
```